# How do I move a Perforce "workspace" folder?

Tags: directory, perforce, move

I've just downloaded a 4.5GB depot to a location on my hard drive that is not ideal.

I'd like to move the folder that Perforce now sees as the "workspace" folder (iPhone) to another folder on my hard disk (Project Name), and then use *that* folder as the workspace folder.

Is this possible, or do I need to download the entire depot again?

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 67, accepted):

in the P4V application:

Open the Workspace dialog:
Go to Connection>Edit Current Workspace...
change "Workspace root:" to where you like

If you have not already moved the files, P4V will offer to copy them for you.

Comment: Although a few years late, this should now be marked as the answer. i manually moved my workspace in the windows file system then updated using this answer in p4v and everything worked seamlessly even knew which files i had checked out etc

Comment: It offers to copy the files for you if you didn't manually copy first.

Comment: It appears to be copying from the server, not from the local copy.  'p4 sync -f c:\RA\...#head'  This may not be ideal if you're on a VPN or have a large stream (or both)

Comment: Careful though: If you have unsynced changes (ex: marked for add or checkouts with changes), they won't be moved to the new location. It's probably better to submit everything to the server first. Or, if you don't want to submit now, move the folder manually (in Explorer) then do a Reconcile Offline Work.

Comment: P4V 2017.3 does *not* offer to copy the workspace files.  You must do it manually.

Answer (score 25):

As long as you know what changelist you last synced to, you can do this without having to sync again. Here's how:

1. Note the last changelist synced
2. Copy/move the folder to the new location
3. Update your workspace (either the root, or the depot mapping) to point at the new location
4. Run `p4 flush //depot/path/to/folder/...@<last_changelist>`

The [flush](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/flush.html) command tells the server that you have the files at the path specified, at the changelist specified. It's a synonym for `p4 sync -k`.

Comment: Are you certain that you need to run `p4 sync -k`? I do not remember having to do that when moving a workspace (changing the root).

Comment: I'm not 100% on that, just part of what I've done the few times I've changed my root. What you said in your answer makes sense, though. When I have some spare time (hopefully soon) I'll set up a workspace to test it out.

Comment: OK, thanks for the info chaps. I ended up syncing again, but if I need to this again in the future I will check it it. Ta.

Comment: It's also worth noting that you should not have any files checked out while you do this, or you will need to do some extra work (`p4 revert -k` the files and re-open them for edit afterward, or shelve the changelist and unshelve it afterward).

Comment: Using p4v 2011.1/392576, I only had to do steps 2 and 3.

Comment: The command line command "`p4 client`" re-opens the client spec for those that need to change root.

Comment: This answer is great except for its very first sentence "As long as you know what changelist you last synced to,..." Fortunately I found that it's possible to refer to the "have list" of *another* workspace with the @syntax: `p4 flush file@other_workspace`

Answer (score 9):

Mike's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030296/how-do-i-move-a-perforce-workspace-folder/7030688#7030688) is almost correct, except that the `p4 sync -k` is not required when moving a workspace (changing the root). P4 does not care where the root is, it only tracks the files on your machine by workspace/client name.

If you wanted to change the workspace name (which would require you to create a **new** workspace) and populate it with files from an already synced workspace, you would then need to run `p4 sync -k` to let the server know that this new workspace has these files at `@changeset`.

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct.  When moved my workspace, P4 definitely didn't recognize any of the files as being part of version control at all until I ran a `p4 sync -k`.  Perhaps this has changed since the answer was originally posted?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using any client (ie: P4V), then you can edit workspace and change the root to the new workspace path.

Comment: Unless things have changed with P4V, just changing the root will require you to sync the files again.

Comment: Things appear to have changed. I'm using p4v 2011.1/392576 and all I did was rename the folder on my hard drive and change the workspace root in p4v.