# Perforce not syncing all files

Tags: perforce

Here, i am facing little different situation. When i got the latest revision from depot, out of 48,805 files i got only 48,771. The remaining 34 files showing error like below

**"The file size is too long"**  FOr this issue what is the better solution?

Comment: Can you cut-and-paste the *exact* message you got? Or paste in a screen-shot? The message text that you have shown is not a normal Perforce message.

Comment: I'm thinking the "file size is too long" is not the actual message.

Answer (score 1):

This question is well answered [here](http://forums.perforce.com/index.php?/topic/418-the-file-name-is-too-long/). The file name length limitation comes from Windows. If you can, shorten your `Workspace root` path.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the link given by @emartel, it is a windows limitation Perforce can't help you much however you can choose your workspace smartly. By default Perforce sets workspace same as server path (which usually will be bigger in size).[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030296/how-do-i-move-a-perforce-workspace-folder) will help you in changing it.