# Copying a Workspace/Folders by USB instead of Getting Latest Revision Online

Tags: perforce

I have a pretty huge project that I host on an external Perforce server. The project is about 13GB.

I have setup a new machine and want to transfer my workspace to the new machine. Copy/Pasting by USB and indicating to perforce that these are the same files seems to not work.

Syncing directly with the server (get latest revision) will take a very long time (slow download speed on my end, 13GB of files).

I am using P4V and am familiar with the P4 command line. Is there anyway I can move over my project in an "offline" matter?

Comment: Certainly, the option is called "reconcile offline work" in the p4v Actions menu. 

See:
http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4v/Offline.html and http://ftp.perforce.com/perforce/r08.2/doc/help/p4v-html-pure/Offline.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I do that, the new copied files, which should be identical to what's on the other computer and the perforce server, yet it tells me I have new files I should upload. Is that normal?

Comment: This is a similar question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030296/how-do-i-move-a-perforce-workspace-folder, with the additional twist of changing machines.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you've already copied the files over and created a client spec that maps them appropriately.  Once that's done, I would use the command line and do:

```
p4 flush ...
p4 clean -n ...  (just to make sure I'm not about to force-sync the world)
p4 clean ...
```

The "p4 flush" is how you tell the server that you "have" everything at the head revision; the "p4 clean" asks the server to double-check and make sure that you actually have everything you just told it you have (and nothing else), and fix anything that's different.

If the "p4 clean -n" shows that everything is about to be "added" to the workspace it probably means the mapping is off; if everything is being "refreshed" it means the files are in the right places but they look different now compared to the head revisions, which might be a problem with P4CHARSET (for unicode files) or LineEnd (for text files).

Another variation could be to specify the time of the USB backup on the "p4 flush":

```
p4 flush ...@yyyy/mm/dd:hh:mm:ss
```

which will probably result in the "p4 clean" having absolutely nothing to do, which is good; then a normal "p4 sync" will get you up to date with whatever got submitted since you made your backup.

See this blog post for more on the "p4 clean" command: http://www.perforce.com/blog/140501/p4-clean-make-workspace-shine